# Why there is a difference Between the Output of the two similar PHP Code

Tags: php, compilation, runtime, interpreter

PHP Code 1

```
<?php 
 $a = 0.03;
 $b = 0.01 + 0.02;
 var_dump($a == $b);
?>
```

Output 1

```
bool(true)
```

PHP Code 2

```
<?php 
 $a = 0.3;
 $b = 0.1 + 0.2;
 var_dump($a == $b);
?>
```

Output 2

```
bool(false)
```

What is the Difference between the above two codes, Why its lead to two different Output.
Can anyone please provide me the explanation which i seek. I am kind of Confused by looking at this.

Comment: Replace 0.1 and add  0.01 in second code

Comment: output is correct , but mistake in your variable

Comment: check and compare both variable

Comment: The reason is that is you go farther to the right of the decimal point, you get into smaller and smaller numbers. 

By the same token, 0.01 is less than 0.5 
0.05 is less than 0.1, but more than 0.01. 

0.004 is less than 0.01.

Comment: @GauravNarula I totally know how the Decimal things work, My Question is about  how there is a difference between the two output, According to me the output will be `bool(true)` for both the code.

Comment: because when you add 0.1+0.4 = 0.5 which is less than 1 means false.